# Problem plotting vector field with ListVectorPlot[]

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a vector field with vectors that displace 0.1 to the right.
When I execute the code with the value `xdis=0.1` I have for a result this:

[image]

The problem of this graph is that it doesn't show the displacement uniformly, contrary to the value `xdis= 0.5` where it works perfectly:

[image]

I really fail to see where is the problem. Here I share the code I'm using.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

```
ibigsize = {39, 39};

{xdis, ydis} = {0.1, 0.0};

origin[{x_, y_}] := {x - xdis, y - ydis};

tablepos = Table[{x, y},
   {y, Range[1, ibigsize[[2]], 1]}, 
   {x, Range[1, ibigsize[[1]], 1]}
   ];

tablev = Table[{x, y} - origin[{x, y}],
   {y, Range[1, ibigsize[[2]], 1]},
   {x, Range[1, ibigsize[[1]], 1]}
   ];


resreal = {tablepos, tablev};
resreal = Flatten[resreal, {{2}, {3}, {1}, {4}}];

ListVectorPlot[resreal,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 VectorPoints -> All,
 VectorScaling -> Automatic,
 VectorSizes -> Small,
 VectorColorFunction -> Automatic
 ]
```

Comment: The culprit is: `VectorScaling -> Automatic`. I think this is a bug and should be reported to support@wolfram.com